# Unable to slice the frame and still use it for the landmarks

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, dlib

Good day Everyone, hope you are all doing well. I am finding it difficult to get the x,y,h,w using dlib as faces = detector(gray) in python. here is the code below. Thank you in advance.

```
#load the detector
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
#load the predictor
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
while True:
frame = webcam.read()
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
 faces = detector(gray)
 for face in faces:
 #face landmarks
 landmarks = predictor(gray, face)
        
 x, y = face.left(), face.top()
 x1, y1 = face.right(), face.bottom()
 frame_img = frame[x,y,x1,y1]
 print(frame_img)
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting from above code?

Comment: This is the error IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-67cf4ce9a4c2> in <module>
    118         x, y = face.left(), face.top()
    119         x1, y1 = face.right(), face.bottom()
--> 120         frame_img = frame[x,y,x1,y1]
    121         print(frame_img)
    122 #         gaze_ratio_left_eye = get_gaze_ratio([36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41], landmarks)

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 3-dimensional, but 4 were indexed

Comment: IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 3-dimensional, but 4 were indexed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error is in this expression: frame[x,y,x1,y1]. Try to replace it with this:

```
frame_img = frame[y:y1,x:x1]
```